# I need a Python 3 class composition structure with class inheritance. How do I accomplish this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to include some objects into a parent class, but those objects need to be able to access the parent class methods and attributes.

The problem, is that I have a ***has-a*** relationship instead of an ***is-a*** relationship. This typically suggests a composition structure, but composition makes it harder to access the parent class object's methods and attributes.

I have this sample code to illustrate what I need:

```
class Body:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_obj = Head() # << head_obj is now part of Body object
        # ...Set-up body...

    def body_actions(self):
        print('Body does something')

    def common_method(self):
        print('Body does something Head can do') # << Head needs this method

class Head:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...Set-up head...

    def head_actions(self):
        print('Head does something')
        Body.common_method() # <<This call does not work without inheritance
```

In the above code, a `Head` object needs to be instantiated by `Body`, and the `Head` object should be able to access the methods in `Body`. This implies a kind of hybrid inheritance and composition structure, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: "the Head object should be able to access the methods in Body" <- why?

Comment: I store all of my data in the primary class object and its sub-objects need to access that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make this work by passing the current instance of Body into Head:

```
class Body:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_obj = Head(self)

...

class Head:
    def __init__(self, body_obj):
        self.body_obj = body_obj

    def head_actions(self):
        print('Head does something')
        self.body_obj.common_method()
```

But really I think you should rethink your design. This adds a large amount of coupling between the two classes, and makes it very confusing.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer on an alternative design that would allow me to do something similar? I want a single Class to represent the whole Body, but I am not tied to a particular design.